Using SMOTE Train Model and Optimal Cutoff on Unbalanced Test Data
My original dataset has a binary dependent variable with 3% of the values being one. First, I split the original dataset into training and testing sets using an 80-20 split. Since it includes both numeric and binary independent variables, I am using SMOTENC (in R) on the training set to create a balanced training dataset. I generate a logistic regression model on this balanced dataset and use the F-Measure as the metric to determine the optimal cutoff.
However, what cutoff should I use on the test dataset?
Since it is unbalanced, using the optimal cutoff found from the balanced training dataset is disastrous.

Why did you run SMOTE in the first place?

@Dave - my original dataset is very imbalanced.  SMOTENC creates a balanced dataset, on which to generate a logistic regression model.

But why create a balanced dataset?

@Dave - The problem with a model trained on imbalanced data is that the model learns that it can achieve high accuracy by consistently predicting the majority class, even if recognizing the minority class is equal or more important when applying the model to a real-world scenario.  https://medium.com/cord-tech/introduction-to-balanced-and-imbalanced-datasets-in-machine-learning-be60c6eeb8be

A logistic regression does not predict categories. After all, your goal is to fiddle with the threshold in order to change the classifications, yet the logistic regression does not change. Thus, I still don’t see the problem. Perhaps refer to some of the posts linked in my profile.

I agree with your first two sentences.  But the point of the testing dataset is to use the logistic regression model and cutoff determined using the training dataset on never-before-seen data.  My point is that an optimal cutoff determined from a balanced dataset will (likely) not work well on a heavily unbalanced dataset.  That is the ultimate problem.

So why did you balance the data?

@Dave - I am bit confused, why would balancing the data not be appropriate? Isn't it recommended to balance the data when the goal is prediction?

You’re seeing how balancing the data causes problems downstream when you want to predict. Maybe some people do recommend doing so, but that advice seems to lead to problems. If you look through material linked in my profile, you will see plenty of pushback from statisticians on this matter of statistics.
